# Create leftjoin with queryBuilder doctrine on symfony 4.1

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

i am try to make a leftjoin but i am getting this sql error
[image]

So I have two Entity Post and Comments
1-Post

```
<?php

 namespace App\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use App\Utils\Slugger;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
 class Post
 {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
   private $id;

   /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,unique=true)
   */
   private $title;
```

I have more Field but is not necessary fort the question.

And Comments Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentsRepository")
  */
 class Comments
 {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;


   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post")
    */
    private $post;
```

In this entity i have the relationship ManyToOne and everything is fine.

So my problem is that i am trying to get all post comments on the PostRepository (I dont see necessary create a CommentRepository for one method)
This is my PostRepositoy

```
<?php
 namespace App\Repository;
 use App\Entity\Post;
 use App\Entity\Comments;
 use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
 use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
 class PostRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
 {
     public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
     {
       parent::__construct($registry, Post::class);
     }

   public function findComments($post)
   {

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin(Comments::class,'c')
        ->andWhere('c.post = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $post)
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
   }
```

can anyone help me ? i can use dql or createQuery and use other option, but i wanna do it this way but i think the query is not the correct.

Comment: Well, I suppose the problem may be with that left join statement itself `leftJoin(Comments::class,'c')` - I am not sure it's recognized as a valid left join, try replacing it to be something like `leftJoin('p.comments', 'c')` (Assuming you have one-to-many relationship field called $comments in your Post entity).

Comment: And if the main aim is to get the Comments data, you should probably move the query to `CommentsRepository`

Comment: Try `->leftJoin('p.comments')->where('c.post = :val')`. Notice the `->where()` and not `->andWhere()`. The `andWhere` adds `AND` clause, assuming that there is already a `WHERE` present. But in your case isn't.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer

Comment: I dont have comment field on post entity and using createQuery is working fine, using this for example 
       `$em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $result = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT u
        FROM App:Comments u
        WHERE u.post = :post');
        $result->setParameter('post', $post);

        try{
            return $result->getResult();
        }catch (\Exception $error){
            return false;
        }`

but i wanna trying using queryBuilder, but thanks guys